# How to format dateFormat in [ngModel] in angular 2?

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, date-formatting, angular-date-format

How to format date like dd-MM-YYYY in [ngModel] ?

```
<input type="text" class="displayInfo"  disabled ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="WarrentItem.dateOfRegistartion">
```

Comment: use `pipe` in angular, I think that should do the job

Answer (score 1):

you can use date pipe directly to display the date with particular format

```
<p> {{WarrentItem.dateOfRegistartion | date: 'dd/MM/YYYY'}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove () in `[ngModel]`

```
<input type="text" class="displayInfo"  disabled ngDefaultControl [ngModel]="dateOfRegistartion | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztqvfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: its ok , but i've got today's Date, i dont need that. I need to get a date from mssql in this format.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

**Method1**

```
<input [ngModel]="startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" type="date" name="startDate"/>
```

**Method 2:**

**Template**

```
<input [ngModel]="humanDate" type="date" name="startDate"/>
```

**Component (TS):**

```
export class App {
  startDate: any;

  constructor() {
    this.startDate = new Date(2005, 1, 4);
  }

  set humanDate(e){
    e = e.split('-');
    let d = new Date(Date.UTC(e[0], e[1]-1, e[2]));
    this.startDate.setFullYear(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate());
  }

  get humanDate(){
    return this.startDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }
}
```